# Can we have class name with alphanumeric character?

Tags: c#

Can we name class using alphanumeric values ?like class Tier1, Tier2 and so on.Is this come under good practice. What is the recommendation around naming class. I know this is very generic question and simple one however there were instance during code review I often came across class names which seems to be usual.

Comment: You could name the classes whatever makes sense for you and your coworkers (inside the rules of the language). Good practice? No if you ask me (a stranger on the net)

Comment: @Jameson That duplicate is for Java, not C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, classes can be named **only** with alphanumeric characters, meaning `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`. You should also make the first letter of a class **C**apital.